# separate uisearchbar & uitableview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a problem, there is a way to separate the uisearchbar from uitableview?I want to put the searchbar at the top of the view, a little tableview at the bottom of view and an image between the 2 items?
thank you

kikko

Comment: how are you building the interface? programatically or withint a nib?

Comment: @Jordan: I building the interface with  a nib - @user ok excuse me!

Comment: so where's the problem? just put the searchbar at the top and the tableview at the bottom?

Comment: if I put the searchbar out of tableview when I search a word it work, it find the word, if I click on the cell I go to detail view (all ok) but when I go back to tableview controller the app crash and I get an error: sigabrt

Comment: try running instruments (esp. zombie tool) to find out why it crashes!

Comment: solved...I find the error and I separate searchbar & tableview